# Are "char s[]" and "char *s" equivalent function arguments?

Tags: c

If there is a function that is declared as 
**void foo(char s[])** and another is declared as **void goo(char *s)** , then are the two declarations equivalent?

Comment: Yes, the prototypes are equivalent.  `foo` receives a pointer to `char` in both cases.  Check the latest online version of the C language standard [N1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.3.2.1, paragraph 3, and section 6.7.6.3, paragraph 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, an array always decays to a pointer when passed to a function as an argument.

This will print the same result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char* arg, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%c", arg[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void bar(char arg [], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%c", arg[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    foo("Hello, World!", 13);

    bar("Hello, World!", 13);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out 
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```